# Multiple key title and splitting of legends in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

The following is simple Gnuplot code for plotting of multiple data sets

```
set terminal postscript eps enhanced colour font 'Times-Roman,12' size 4in,4in  
set output "UCl3-AgCl.eps"
set style line 1 lt 2 lw 4 lc rgb "red"
set style line 2 lt 3 lw 4 lc rgb "dark-green"
set style line 3 lt 4 lw 4 lc rgb "blue"
set style line 4 lt 5 lw 4 lc rgb "orange"
set style line 5 lt 6 lw 4 lc rgb "dark-magenta"

set xtics out scale 1.5 
set ytics out scale 1.5
set tics font ", 14"
set xlabel "Temperature" font "Times-Bold,16"
set ylabel "Potential vs. Ag^{+}|Ag (V)" font "Times-Bold,16"
set key inside left bottom  
set key samplen 5 spacing 1.5 font "Times-Bold,14" width -1.0
set yrange [-1.25:-1.55]

plot [660:820] 'UCl3-AgCl.dat' u 1:2 title "1 wt.% UCl_{3}" with points lt -1 pt 1 ps 1.4, \
'UCl3-AgCl.dat' u 3:4 title "2 wt.% UCl_{3}" with points lt -1 pt 2 ps 1.4, \
'UCl3-AgCl.dat' u 5:6 title "3 wt.% UCl_{3}" with points lt -1 pt 3 ps 1.4, \
'UCl3-AgCl.dat' u 7:8 title "1 wt.% UCl_{3}" with points lt -1 pt 1 ps 1.4, \
'UCl3-AgCl.dat' u 9:10 title "2 wt.% UCl_{3}" with points lt -1 pt 2 ps 1.4, \
'UCl3-AgCl.dat' u 1:2 title "3 wt.% UCl_{3}" with points lt -1 pt 3 ps 1.4
```

Data file is attached

```
# EMF data of UCl3 in LiCl-KCl eutectic melt
# using 1 and 5 wt.% AgCl 
# Composition of UCl3: 1, 2 and 3 wt.% UCl3 
# Data set 1: 1 wt.% AgCl 
# Col 1: T1(K) Col 2: EMF1 ( 1 wt.% UCl3), Col 3: T2(K), Col 4: EMF2 (2 wt.% UCl3), Col 5: T3(K), Col 6: EMF3 (3 wt.% UCl3) 
# Data set 2: 5 wt.% AgCl 
# Col 7: T1(K) Col 8: EMF1 ( 1 wt.% UCl3), Col 9: T2(K), Col 10: EMF2 (2 wt.% UCl3), Col 11: T3(K), Col 12: EMF3 (3 wt.% UCl3) 
693   -1.4061   693   -1.3889    673   -1.4061      693   -1.5227    693   -1.5089      673    -1.5232
673   -1.4202   673   -1.4013    699   -1.3812      673   -1.5320    673   -1.5235      699    -1.4990
703   -1.3989   699   -1.3859    713   -1.3671      703   -1.5181    699   -1.5057      713    -1.4920
713   -1.3918   703   -1.3801    683   -1.3947      713   -1.5134    703   -1.5022      683    -1.5144
683   -1.4135   713   -1.3725    723   -1.3592      683   -1.5278    713   -1.4970      723    -1.4812
723   -1.3854   683   -1.3992    734   -1.3509      723   -1.5064    683   -1.5169      734    -1.4732
734   -1.3785   723   -1.3700    743   -1.3470      734   -1.5041    723   -1.4949      743    -1.4670
743   -1.3702   734   -1.3635    749   -1.3387      743   -1.4983    734   -1.4949      749    -1.4629
754   -1.3632   743   -1.3559    754   -1.3394      754   -1.4937    743   -1.4849      754    -1.4574
773   -1.3509   749   -1.3481    773   -1.3086      773   -1.4846    749   -1.4791      773    -1.4363
783   -1.3437   754   -1.3475    789   -1.2969      783   -1.4797    754   -1.4794      789    -1.4267
                764   -1.3405                                        764   -1.4746
                773   -1.3332                                        773   -1.4689
                783   -1.3348                                        783   -1.4712
                789   -1.3270                                        789   -1.4651
                799   -1.3217                                        799   -1.4620
```

Now I wish to have two different keys; one for first three data sets and the other one for last three datasets. It should be something like

```
{/Times-Italic x}_{AgCl} = 1 wt.% 
1 wt.% UCl_{3}
2 wt.% UCl_{3}
3 wt.% UCl_{3}

{/Times-Italic x}_{AgCl} = 5 wt.% 
1 wt.% UCl_{3}
2 wt.% UCl_{3}
3 wt.% UCl_{3}
```

It can be either one below the other or alongside each other. How can the code be accordingly modified? Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Check `help keyentry`, with `keyentry` you can add some extra lines without plotting something. If you don't want to display a symbol set the pointsize to zero.

Be aware, you have data where some columns are longer than other ones. If you have spaces as separator, gnuplot will not recognize the columns as you expect. So, either make sure your separator is tab (`"\t"`). I guess StackOverflow converts `"\t"` to space. Alternatively, insert some symbol, e.g. `?`, to make it clear what the columns are.

By the way, you don't have to type `UCl-AgCl.dat` 6 times, 1 times is enough,  `''` is plotting from the last used file.

The image below is from wxt terminal generated with gnuplot 5.2.6.

**Data:** `UCl3-AgCl.dat`

```
# EMF data of UCl3 in LiCl-KCl eutectic melt
# using 1 and 5 wt.% AgCl 
# Composition of UCl3: 1, 2 and 3 wt.% UCl3 
# Data set 1: 1 wt.% AgCl 
# Col 1: T1(K) Col 2: EMF1 ( 1 wt.% UCl3), Col 3: T2(K), Col 4: EMF2 (2 wt.% UCl3), Col 5: T3(K), Col 6: EMF3 (3 wt.% UCl3) 
# Data set 2: 5 wt.% AgCl 
# Col 7: T1(K) Col 8: EMF1 ( 1 wt.% UCl3), Col 9: T2(K), Col 10: EMF2 (2 wt.% UCl3), Col 11: T3(K), Col 12: EMF3 (3 wt.% UCl3) 
693   -1.4061   693   -1.3889    673   -1.4061      693   -1.5227    693   -1.5089      673    -1.5232
673   -1.4202   673   -1.4013    699   -1.3812      673   -1.5320    673   -1.5235      699    -1.4990
703   -1.3989   699   -1.3859    713   -1.3671      703   -1.5181    699   -1.5057      713    -1.4920
713   -1.3918   703   -1.3801    683   -1.3947      713   -1.5134    703   -1.5022      683    -1.5144
683   -1.4135   713   -1.3725    723   -1.3592      683   -1.5278    713   -1.4970      723    -1.4812
723   -1.3854   683   -1.3992    734   -1.3509      723   -1.5064    683   -1.5169      734    -1.4732
734   -1.3785   723   -1.3700    743   -1.3470      734   -1.5041    723   -1.4949      743    -1.4670
743   -1.3702   734   -1.3635    749   -1.3387      743   -1.4983    734   -1.4949      749    -1.4629
754   -1.3632   743   -1.3559    754   -1.3394      754   -1.4937    743   -1.4849      754    -1.4574
773   -1.3509   749   -1.3481    773   -1.3086      773   -1.4846    749   -1.4791      773    -1.4363
783   -1.3437   754   -1.3475    789   -1.2969      783   -1.4797    754   -1.4794      789    -1.4267
  ?         ?   764   -1.3405      ?         ?        ?         ?    764   -1.4746        ?          ?
  ?         ?   773   -1.3332      ?         ?        ?         ?    773   -1.4689        ?          ?
  ?         ?   783   -1.3348      ?         ?        ?         ?    783   -1.4712        ?          ?
  ?         ?   789   -1.3270      ?         ?        ?         ?    789   -1.4651        ?          ?
  ?         ?   799   -1.3217      ?         ?        ?         ?    799   -1.4620        ?          ?
```

**Code:**

```
### "split" key
reset session

# set terminal postscript eps enhanced colour font 'Times-Roman,12' size 4in,4in  
# set output "UCl3-AgCl.eps"
set style line 1 lt 2 lw 4 lc rgb "red"
set style line 2 lt 3 lw 4 lc rgb "dark-green"
set style line 3 lt 4 lw 4 lc rgb "blue"
set style line 4 lt 5 lw 4 lc rgb "orange"
set style line 5 lt 6 lw 4 lc rgb "dark-magenta"

set xtics out scale 1.5 
set ytics out scale 1.5
set tics font ", 14"
set xlabel "Temperature" font "Times-Bold,16"
set ylabel "Potential vs. Ag^{+}|Ag (V)" font "Times-Bold,16"
set key inside left bottom  
set key samplen 5 spacing 1.5 font "Times-Bold,12" width -1.0
set yrange [-1.25:-1.55]

plot [660:820] \
    keyentry w p ps 0 ti "{/Times-Italic x}_{AgCl} = 1 wt.% ", \
    'UCl3-AgCl.dat' u 1:2 ti "1 wt.% UCl_{3}" w lp lt 1 pt 1 ps 1.4, \
    '' u 3:4 ti "2 wt.% UCl_{3}" w lp lt 2 pt 2 ps 1.4, \
    '' u 5:6 ti "3 wt.% UCl_{3}" w lp lt 3 pt 3 ps 1.4, \
    keyentry w p ps 0 ti "{/Times-Italic x}_{AgCl} = 5 wt.% ", \
    '' u 7:8 ti "1 wt.% UCl_{3}" w lp lt 4 pt 1 ps 1.4, \
    '' u 9:10 ti "2 wt.% UCl_{3}" w lp lt 5 pt 2 ps 1.4, \
    '' u 11:12 ti "3 wt.% UCl_{3}" w lp lt 6 pt 3 ps 1.4

set output
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]